# Point Rails app to specific domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an new rails application but on an existing website. The main point is that I don't really need to touch the existing application, as it will be more consider an extension.

I need to make this url: 'www.my_webiste.com/foo' to point to a rails app, as www.my_website.com is already built and hosted. My Rails.root should return "www.my_webiste.com/foo". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a subdomain for the app.

Make it something like **my_app.my_website.com**.

Rails apps need a unique root to be properly hosted